lagrange interpolation estimate in finite element analysis
It suddenly occurred to me that when we apply the Bramble-Hilbert lemma to estimate the error, we have something like
\begin{equation}
||v-\Pi v||_0\leq Ch^{k}|v|_{k}
\end{equation}
where the interpolation is defined as $\Pi:H^k(\Omega)\to P^k(\Omega)$ or piecewise $P^k$ spaces. And we think $h<1$, so when $k$ increases, we say that $\Pi v$ approximate to $v$. However, when $k$ increases, the constant $C$ changes, since the interpolation space changes, and the $|v|_k$ changes. In this sense, how can we say that $\Pi v$ is going 'near' $v$ when k increasing? Can we prove that for $l<k$, the following holds?
\begin{equation}
||v-\Pi_k v||_0\leq ||v-\Pi_l v||_0
\end{equation}
